# Automatically displaying a range of days for a month after a given month is selected

Tags: php

I have this dilemma that am in but i can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I have this form that i have written, which is working pretty well so far but i would to make so that when
i select a month in the select tag of with attribute name="month" it automatically displays the corresponding range of days from
1 to the number of days in that month in the select tag with attribute name="day" like as defined in the monthDays array in my code.

Which would be the best way to go about it because i don't want to use javaScript because am not so good at it and i purely wanted to keep it in HTML and PHP
Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $startYear = 1970;
        $years = (int)date('Y') - $startYear;

        $monthDays = array(
            "January" => 31, "February" => 28, "March" => 31, "April" => 30,
            "May" => 31, "June" => 30, "July" => 31, "August" => 31,
            "September" => 30, "October" => 31, "November" => 30, "December" => 31
        );
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="dob">Date of birth</label></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $months = array_keys($monthDays);
                        $days = array_values($monthDays);
                    ?>
                    <select name="month">
                        <?php
                            foreach($months as $key => $month) {
                                $x = $key + 1;
                                echo "<option value=\"$x\">$month</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <select name="day">
                        <?php
                            for($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++) {
                                $x = $i + 1;
                                echo "<option value=\"$x\">$x</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <select name="year">
                        <?php
                            for($i = 0; $i <= $years; $i++) {
                                $selectedYear = $startYear + $i;
                                echo "<option value=\"{$selectedYear}\">{$selectedYear}</option>\n";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: You need to use javascript to dynamically add/change content on your page.

Comment: The alternative for using javascript is: select a month, submit the form, read the selected month in php, display the days, send it back to the client.

Comment: You could pull it off by calling your php script everytime you post the month from your form. Edit: this is essentially what @Michel suggested.